# Mocha - unable to implement TestFunction interface methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying implement following method in my test case from `TestFunction` interface from `Moacha`

`(fn: Func): Test;`

here is the implementation

```
describe("testing get request", () => {
    it(() => {
        const res = request(app).get("/get-page");
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    });
});
```

The error I get is this:

`TypeError: Test argument "title" should be a string. Received type "function"`

when I add the title in `it` before the the anonymous function it works fine. any idea why I am not able to implement the method that only takes a function.

The interface from `index.d.ts`

```
interface TestFunction {
        (fn: Func): Test;
        (fn: AsyncFunc): Test;
        (title: string, fn?: Func): Test;
        (title: string, fn?: AsyncFunc): Test;
        only: ExclusiveTestFunction;
        skip: PendingTestFunction;
        retries(n: number): void;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the `(fn: Func): Test;` method signature from?

Comment: its in the library source, its part of the ```TestFunction``` interface

Comment: Could you link to it?

Comment: if you can please read my comment under your answer I have explained how I was able to see that interface

Comment: @Titulum I assume the typings being used are from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [code for the `it` keyword](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/interfaces/bdd.js), there is no method that accepts only a function (without a title). As far as I can see in the [documentation of Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), not a single time is an `it` keyword called without the title. So, your code should use it too:

```js
describe("testing get request", () => {
    it("should return statuscode 200", () => {
        const res = request(app).get("/get-page");
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    });
});
```

EDIT: If you take a look at the source of [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts) in the  [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), you can see that the [`it`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L605), [`test`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L605) and [`specify`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L2325) keywords all reference the [`TestFunction` interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L430). This interface indeed specifies `(fn: AsyncFunc): Test;` as a valid signature, but this is nowhere to be found in the Mocha documentation.

[We can see that the `TestFunction` interface was added to replace the `ITestDefinition` some 2 years back](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/6bddfd9921357e6dea040dee8724717a6d3a1e86#diff-6382e04d36916e2e024c09fb5e10e4e6R2614), and the original `ITestDefinition` does not allow the use of a function without a title. The message of the commit introducing these changes is "More robust Mocha definitions". Why this was added, I don't know. I suspect that it is due to another package, [`mocha-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-typescript), also depending on the [DefinitelyTyped typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mocha/index.d.ts), and this package probably needed the `(fn: Func): Test;` signature in order to be correctly validated by typescript.

In the end, the result is that Mocha does not allow `it` to be used without a title.

Comment: Thanks I am new to JavaScript, I am using VS code and when I ```Ctrl + click``` on ```it``` it takes me to that interface in a file called ```index.d.ts``` and in that interface I see variations of the method. Adding title got me into another issue which is resolved when I put ```async``` before ```() -> {``` and then use await before ```request(app).get``` any idea why that might be?

Comment: Ah I see. The [`index.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) is a file that is used by Typescript to support javascript file without converting them to Typescript.

Comment: right, so if I want to look at the documentation I should look at git rather than using the tool to navigate to the source right?

Comment: Well, it depends. What you did is not wrong, the `index.d.ts` should tell you what method signatures are accepted, but I do not know how the `index.d.ts` file for Mocha differentiates between `describe`, `context`, `it`... Your best bet is indeed to go look at the official documentation!

Comment: just updated the post and pasted the interface that got me confused, for me only this one works ```(title: string, fn?: AsyncFunc): Test;```

Comment: I did some more investigation and found some clues as to why it could have been added as a valid signature.

Comment: Thanks Titulum, I have got no idea what is DefinitelyTyped I will look into this to understand what this all mean, Thanks a lot for you time, and happy new year!

Comment: Happy new year!